# VB.net & Access query

Tags: vb.net

Im currently doing a vb.net project for college and want to create a new access record using textboxes, masked textboxes and richtextboxes using the vb gui. However I keep getting this exception:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

Here is my code which is working on other forms

```
Private Sub btnSaveNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveNew.Click
    Dim objrow As DataRow

    objrow = objDataSet.Tables("tblEngineersReport").NewRow

    objrow.Item("To") = txtTo.Text
    objrow.Item("Date_Carried_Out") = txtCompletedDate.Text
    objrow.Item("Description_Of_Work") = txtWorkDescription.Text
    objrow.Item("Comment") = txtComment.Text
    objrow.Item("Quantity1") = txtQuantity1.Text
    objrow.Item("Quantity2") = txtQuantity2.Text
    objrow.Item("Quantity3") = txtQuantity3.Text
    objrow.Item("Quantity4") = txtQuantity4.Text
    objrow.Item("Item_Description1") = txtDescription.Text
    objrow.Item("Item_Description2") = txtDescription2.Text
    objrow.Item("Item_Description3") = txtDescription3.Text
    objrow.Item("Item_Description4") = txtDescription4.Text
    objrow.Item("Unit_Price1") = txtUnitPrice1.Text
    objrow.Item("Unit_Price2") = txtUnitPrice2.Text
    objrow.Item("Unit_Price3") = txtUnitPrice3.Text
    objrow.Item("Unit_Price4") = txtUnitPrice4.Text
    objrow.Item("Rate1") = txtRate1.Text
    objrow.Item("Rate2") = txtRate2.Text
    objrow.Item("Rate3") = txtRate3.Text
    objrow.Item("Labour1") = txtDescription5.Text
    objrow.Item("Labour2") = txtDescription6.Text
    objrow.Item("Labour3") = txtDescription7.Text
    objrow.Item("Hours_Worked1") = txtHours1.Text
    objrow.Item("Hours_Worked2") = txtHours2.Text
    objrow.Item("Hours_Worked3") = txtHours3.Text

    objDataSet.Tables("tblEngineersReport").Rows.Add(objrow)
    objEngineerDA.Update(objDataSet, "tblEngineersReport")

    Retrieve()

    MessageBox.Show("new record added")
    cboJobID.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

the Quanity textboxes down to the hours worked are contained within a table layout panel and am just wondering would this have anything to do with the record not saving?

Comment: Is there any conversion that needs to be done? Can you maybe show the design of the table?

Comment: Are you sure all of the columns in the db table is of type `Text`?

Comment: no there of type number and date/time aswell, does that matter?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the names of your columns I could notice that you have a column named **TO**. This is a reserved keyword in MS-Access and thus the autogenerated queries for your adapter will have a syntax error if you don't tell to your `OleDbCommandBuilder` to encapsulate the column names with the appropriate [QuotePrefix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder.quoteprefix(v=vs.110).aspx) and QuoteSuffix string.

You need to add this code, just after the declaration and initialization of your OleDbCommandBuilder-

```
 Dim builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(objEngineerDA)
 builder.QuotePrefix = "["
 builder.QuoteSuffix = "]"
```

Comment: It is the same Syntax Error as before? Did you add the QuotePrefix and QuoteSuffix to your OleDbCommandBuilder before generating the INSERT/UPDATE commands?

Comment: I didn't, where do i add this?

Comment: To execute the Update command of any dataadapter you need to have the `InsertCommand/UpdateCommand/DeleteCommand` properties of the adapter set to valid `OleDbCommands`. You could do this manually or using an `OleDbCommandBuilder` as shown in my answer. The declaration and initialization of the OleDbCommandBuilder should be done just after you have set your OleDbDataAdapter named objEngineerDA with the command that Select records from your table If you add the code that initializes the objEngineerDA I could be more precise in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check the INSERT statement used in the definition of your DataAdapter (objEngineerDA).  The syntax of that INSERT is apparently incorrect, according to the error.  Without seeing what is currently there, I cannot advise as to what is wrong with it.